# Analysis services target server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 with SSDT installed, my database is held in SQL Server 2014. When I start a new analysis project and include my DB from SQL Server, everything seems to be fine, but when I click mining model viewer the message box pops up and tells me that it's unable to connect to server.

In properties I changed target server from localhost to my SQL Server 2014 (`ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS`) instance that I'm using to hold my database. But it tells me the same thing.

What is target server actually? And what should I use there to make it work?

Comment: Is Analysis Server service running?

Comment: Analysis Services is not included in SQL Server Express Edition.  Consider using Developer Edition instead.